# Replace Canvas Image in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

I have a program and I want when someone clicks a button, the canvas image will change. My code is below:

```
from PIL import ImageTk,Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import tkinter
import textwrap
from tkinter import Frame, Canvas, Text, INSERT, END


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("296x337")
root.resizable(False, False)

im=Image.open("red.jpg")  
photo=ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)  
cv = tkinter.Canvas()  
cv.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')  
cv.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='nw')

def changepic():
    ###place where I want to change the Canvas Image
    print("change color")#I added this because python wouldn't let me run thee function without something.


a2=tkinter.Button(root,text='change color',bd=0, command=changepic)
a2.config(highlightbackground='black')
a2.place(x=135, y=70)
```

Comment: Why a canvas image instead of a standard Label image?

Comment: I got it, thanks Novel for the idea of using a standard Label image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Canvas, I replaced the code so that it prints the image using tkinter.Label:

```
from PIL import ImageTk,Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import tkinter
import textwrap
from tkinter import Frame, Canvas, Text, INSERT, END


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("296x337")
root.resizable(False, False)

img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("red.jpg"))
panel = tkinter.Label(root, image=img)
panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

def changepic(imagename):
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(imagename))
    panel.configure(image=img2)
    panel.image = img2


a2=tkinter.Button(root,text='change color',bd=0, command=changepic("blue.jpg")
a2.config(highlightbackground='black')
a2.place(x=135, y=70)
```

I got my information from: [How to update the image of a Tkinter Label widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482081/how-to-update-the-image-of-a-tkinter-label-widget)

And: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_label.htm