# Calling an image to apper on Label - Tkinter - Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a begginner programming in Python. I'm using Tkinter library to create a window with a drop down menu. I created a Label for show a country flag when the item is selected on the drop down menu. But somethings is going wrong, nothing happens. Here is my code, I'll be so thankful for who helps me how to procced and fix it.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x450+450+150')
root.title('Python Program')

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

def callFlag():
    photo = PhotoImage('image.png')
    flag = Label(root, text='teste', image=photo)
    flag.pack()

subMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label='Bandeiras', menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label='Mongólia', command=callFlag)
subMenu.add_command(label='Opção 2', command=callFlag)

subMenu2 = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label='Menu 2', menu=subMenu2)
subMenu2.add_command(label='Opção 1', command=callFlag)
subMenu2.add_command(label='Opção 2', command=callFlag)
subMenu2.add_separator()
subMenu2.add_command(label='Exit', command=exit)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Hello. Sorry for mistaking. No errors happens, but nothing happens, as this submenu option has no command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x450+450+150')
root.title('Python Program')

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

def callFlag():
    photo = PhotoImage(file='image.png')
    flag = Label(root, text='teste', image=photo)
    flag.image = photo
    flag.pack()


subMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label='Bandeiras', menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label='Mongólia', command=callFlag)
subMenu.add_command(label='Opção 2', command=callFlag)

subMenu2 = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label='Menu 2', menu=subMenu2)
subMenu2.add_command(label='Opção 1', command=callFlag)
subMenu2.add_command(label='Opção 2', command=callFlag)
subMenu2.add_separator()
subMenu2.add_command(label='Exit', command=exit)

root.mainloop()
```

The catch seems to be avoiding Python's garbage collection as the function exits by keeping an extra reference to `photo` (`flag.image = photo`).

Alternatively, you can the define the image and the flag along with everything else, and pass the flag's `pack()` function in `add_command`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x450+450+150')
root.title('Python Program')

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

photo = PhotoImage(file='image.png')
flag = Label(root, text='teste', image=photo)

subMenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label='Bandeiras', menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label='Mongólia', command=flag.pack)
subMenu.add_command(label='Opção 2', command=flag.pack)

subMenu2 = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)
menu.add_cascade(label='Menu 2', menu=subMenu2)
subMenu2.add_command(label='Opção 1', command=flag.pack)
subMenu2.add_command(label='Opção 2', command=flag.pack)
subMenu2.add_separator()
subMenu2.add_command(label='Exit', command=exit)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is has worked to me thank you! How about to clean the Label and appear another flag and select another one? I tried to use "flag = Label(root, image=photo)" outside from the "def" but it says the variable "photo" cannot be founded

Comment: That's a different question. I think at this point you're better off using `ImageTk` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482081/how-to-update-the-image-of-a-tkinter-label-widget)