# Isn't it 'save' to pass an argument as an option to a radio button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, radio-button

First of all, thank you for reading my problem.

I wanted to create a program that creates a photo print button when a desired animal is selected with a radio button in the Windows interface, and prints a photo with the button.

It seems that the value is stored in the integer variable var by the radio button option, so I called vote_animal, the photo output button function first.

```
def vote_animal():
    button1 = Button(window, text = "Picture", font = (5), fg = "black", command = show_animal)
    button1.place(x = xPos, y = yPos)
```

#main code

```
var = IntVar()
dogRB = Radiobutton(window, text = "Dog", variable = var, value = 1, command = vote_animal) 
catRB = Radiobutton(window, text = "Cat", variable = var, value = 2, command = vote_animal)
rabbitRB = Radiobutton(window, text = "Rabbit", variable = var, value = 3, command = vote_animal)

dogRB.pack()
catRB.pack()
rabbitRB.pack()
```

Then I believed that when the print photo button was clicked, the show_animal function would be called and the function would print the picture according to the var variable.

```
def show_animal():
    if var.get() == 1:
        photo = PhotoImage(file = "C:/picture/"+animalList[var.get()-1])
        label2.configure(image = photo)
        label2.pack()
    
    elif var.get() == 2:
        photo = PhotoImage(file = "C:/picture/"+animalList[var.get()-1])
        label2.configure(image = photo)
        label2.pack()
    
    else :
        photo = PhotoImage(file = "C:/picture/"+animalList[var.get()-1])
        label2.configure(image = photo)
        label2.pack()
```

Oh, for reference, the last path of the photo is implemented as animalList.

```
animalList=["dog.gif", "cat.gif", "rabbit.gif"]
```

Anyway, if I make the code like this, the picture is not printed even though there are no errors. So, I want to ask if the value of var does not apply to the show_animal function, or if there is another problem.

In case you don't know, I've put the code on github.
Github URL: https://github.com/baecci/For_Stackoverflow

The first question may be a bit messy, but I would appreciate your kind answer.

Comment: Since you are programming in Python, presumably you understand that indentation affects the meaning. Python code with missing or messed up indentation does not make sense and cannot be run. Please post a [mre] (in your question, not a link to code on another site).

Answer (score 0):

The display of images is fine, but there are shortcomings in the program.

I recommend these modifications in the code on GitHub:

1. change line 55 to: `photo = PhotoImage(file = "C:/picture/"+animalList[0])`
2. insert per line 56: `label2.photo_ref = photo` (see details [How to update the image of a Tkinter Label widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482081/how-to-update-the-image-of-a-tkinter-label-widget))
3. insert next line: `label2.place(x = 10, y = 200)` (or another location or pack())
4. after line with `label2.configure` insert line `label2.photo_ref = photo`